# jQuery datapicker allow partial date like "05/"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a Date of Birth field rendered as a textbox attached to a datepicker. Here is the html output:

```
<input class="text-box single-line hasDatepicker valid" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Birth Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Birth Date field is required." id="DateOfBirth" name="DateOfBirth" type="datetime" value="">
```

It should not allow a future date. Here is the jQUery code:

```
$('#DateOfBirth').datepicker({ maxDate: '+0d' });
$.validator.addMethod("noFutureDate", function(value) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
        var dob = Date.parse(value);
        var today = new Date();
        if (dob > today) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}, "Birth Date cannot be a future date.");
$('#DateOfBirth').rules('add', { noFutureDate: true });
```

It works well. However, it allows partial date like "05/" and the it translate to date 988689600000. Does datepicker allow partial date to be entered? What's the best way to handle it ? Do i need to add Regex validation rule?

Comment: `Date.parse` and 'new Date()` will make assumptions about numbers that aren't provided. I think a regex will work best in this case, but you may need to consider internationalization (other countries often put the day before the month).

Comment: @Blazemonger: That clarifies my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but see this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/epameb/2/)

You can clear input and left datepicker to handle validation for you.

```
$('input').keyup -> @value = ''
```

Comment: It disables the way to enter a date as a text like "5/1/1970". Using the date picker only to enter an old date will be way too many clicks.